# For a unit-speed curve $\beta$ with unit tangent vector field $T_\beta$, we define the spherical image $\sigma(s)=T_\beta (s)$. Prove that:

Tags: differential-geometry, frenet-frame

For a unit-speed curve $\beta$ with unit tangent vector field $T_\beta$, we define the spherical image $\sigma$ With $\sigma(s)=T_\beta (s)$.

How can I prove that $$\kappa_\sigma=\sqrt{1+(\frac{\tau_\beta}{\kappa_\beta})^2}$$ and $$\tau_\sigma= \frac{(\frac{\tau_\beta}{\kappa_\beta})’}{\kappa_\beta(1+(\frac{\tau_\beta}{\kappa_\beta})^2)}$$

**Here is what I have come up with so far:**

$\sigma’(s)=T_\beta’(s)=\kappa_\beta N_\beta=T_\sigma(s)$
$$\implies T_\sigma’= \sigma’’(s)= \kappa_\beta’N_\beta +\kappa_\beta N_\beta’$$ $$=\kappa_\beta’N_\beta+\kappa_\beta(-\kappa_\beta T_\beta +\tau_\beta B_\beta)$$
$$=\kappa_\beta’ N_\beta +\kappa_\beta \tau_\beta B_\beta -\kappa_\beta^2 T_\beta$$

(Because $\tau_\beta=-B_\beta’\bullet N_\beta$) $$\implies \sigma’’(s)=\kappa_\beta’ N_\beta -\kappa_\beta^2 T_\beta$$

Then  is: $\kappa_\sigma=\frac{\Vert \sigma’\times \sigma’’ \Vert}{v_\beta^3}=\Vert \sigma’\times \sigma’’ \Vert$ $$=\Vert (\kappa_\beta N_\beta) \times (\kappa_\beta’N_\beta -\kappa_\beta^2 T_\beta)\Vert$$
$$=\Vert(\kappa_\beta N_\beta) \times (-\kappa_\beta T_\beta)\Vert= \Vert \kappa_\beta^3 B_\beta \Vert$$

Can somebody help me find my mistake and how I can solve this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: For starters, your first line is trouble. $s$ is not an arclength parameter for $\sigma$ (I’m not sure why you’re writing $\alpha$).

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you for your correction. I miss read my own notes. Late night

Comment: You haven’t yet fixed the important error in the first line!

Comment: @TedShifrin  Can you give me some help with that please? I m not familiar with the way I could arclength parametrize  $\sigma$ or how $\sigma$ is supposed to look like. I know this must sound to you like a stupid question.

Comment: No, not a stupid question, but this is a huge point at the beginning of differential geometry. I don't know what text you are learning from, but I'll suggest you download my differential geometry text (linked in my profile) and read through Section 2 of Chapter 1.

Comment: @TedShifrin thank you very much for your advice. I ll do this now, and give an update on my problem :)